# Can Black Holes process quantum information?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, quantum-information, quantum-gravity, quantum-computer

Seems that spinning black holes are capable of complex quantum information processes with qubits encoded in the X-ray photons emitted by the accretion disk 
https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.06822 - Photonic Bell states creation around rotating black holes

It might be possible that rotating black holes to implement quantum algorithms?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Physics SE. Can you please elaborate a bit more on your question, give a bit of context ? the aim of this site is to maintain a question/awnser database that can be useful to other people in the future.

Comment: BH can be regarded as an information scrambler,which continuously mixes the infalling information by some (unknown) dynamics. From this point of view, it' can be understood as an encoder. And in fact, we can decode the infalling information by observing the BH radiation according to J. Preskill.  Also the MH model of BH radiation can be regarded as a quantum circuit involving closed timelike curve (S. Lloyd), which is definitely a kind of quantum computation.

Comment: But I have no idea how to 'program' this computer.

Comment: So, Yes, BH can and does process quantum information. But we do not understand its program. I think it's possible to explore some part of it by observing the input/output parameter (dropping information into BH and observe the radiation) as done in understand a black box system. But the information obtained in such a way is minor (if not impossible).

Comment: @X.Dong why did you write that as a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: What do you mean by "write quantum algorithms"? An algorithm is a recipe for solving a problem. Black holes certainly don't write algorithms. I think you're asking if a black hole might actually *implement* a  certain algorithms in the sense that it processes quantum information in some way. In this sense, *everything in nature* implements some algorithm. Which are you asking about? I'm voting to close as unclear what you're asking, but please edit the post so we can re-open it.

Comment: DanielSank, give me an example of something in the nature that implements quantum algorithms.

Comment: @user15507 I'd be happy to but it will likely turn into more of a discussion than comments are meant for. Shall we discuss in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=physics.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only scanned the article, so I can't talk about it on an authoritative level. However, I would say this article is on how the extreme frame dragging of a rotating black hole with $a~=~1~-~\epsilon$ for $0~<~\epsilon~<<~1$ acts to prepare entangled states. This is done by correlating states in the Hilbert spaces for polarization and angular momentum. The angular momentum are determined by the frame dragging of the black hole. The frame dragging rotates the polarization states of a photon so that it is identical to the orbital angular momentum state.

This is not about the black hole as a quantum computer, though one might ponder whether the black hole as a quantum system is shifting it angular momentum quantum numbers in a way that transfers quantum entanglement or its phase from the black hole to photons emitted by hot plasma around the black hole.